# When to use std::future and std::promise with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So when I need to return value from the thread without OOP main options are to have a function parameter passed by reference and to use promise-future mechanism.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

void dbl(std::promise<int>&& pr, int x)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));  // (1)simulating some work
    pr.set_value(x*x);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); // (2)continuing doing some work
}

void dbl1(int& x)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));  // simulating some work
    x *= x;
}

int main()
{
  std::promise<int> pr;
  auto fut = pr.get_future();

  std::thread t(dbl, std::move(pr), 5);
  int d = fut.get(); //we are waiting for the result to be ready
  std::cout<<d<<std::endl;  

  std::thread t1(dbl1, std::ref(d));
  t1.join(); //and here we are waiting for the result to be ready
  std::cout<<d<<std::endl;  

  t.join();  //to avoid program abortion in the end      
}
```

So as I see it if the result that I need is the last or the only thing a thread will do I don't really need `promise-future` as just passing a reference will be completely the same, though I need to be more careful about not changing the value in main or other thread.

So when in `dbl` after getting `x` value I need to do something more I can benefit from the `promise-future` as I already can pass to the main thread calculated value, but for `dbl1` `promise-future`  will just be an extra overhead (assuming safety of the passed to the thread value isn't in issue) and passing by reference will be better solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't have anything else to do with the original thread (the one expecting a result from the other thread), and it immediately waits for either the future or the spawned thread to finish, then why don't you have the original thread do the work itself? The *entire point* of futures/promises is to enable concurrency (and possibly parallelism), to *not* wait immediately.

Comment: @EOF but when we call get() from the future we anyway are waiting

Comment: @DoehJohn You are only waiting on the future if it hasn't finished already. You're supposed to launch your async task and go do other things in the meantime.

Comment: @ZanLynx ye, but I can do all the same without future, but passing to the thread value by the reference

Comment: I see no parallelism in your code. The place where you submit work for a thread is the exact same place where you retrieve it, with absolutely no intervening code. That's generally not how parallel processing works.

Comment: Reading **C++ Concurrency in Action** is a must if you are serious about multithreading. Having said that, you should normally use `std::async` for case similar to the above one. future and promise are useful for example if you have a thread pool or if you need to executing code in the UI thread and get the result later from a background thread.